# How to set IconfontCN Color?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I want to change the icon tint color for my Icon component in React, but it's not working.

Here's my code:

```
const CreateIconFont = createFromIconfontCN({
    scriptUrl: '//at.alicdn.com/t/c/font_3378177_orth234lbl.js',
});

interface IconFontProps {
    type: string;
    style?: React.CSSProperties
    className?: string
    onClick?: () => void
}
const IconFont = ({ type, style, className = "", onClick, ...props }: IconFontProps) =>
    <CreateIconFont {...props} onClick={onClick} style={style} type={type} className={className} />

export default IconFont;
```

And then I tried to

```
  <IconFont type="i-zixun" style={{ color: "blue", fontSize: 27 }} />
```

Comment: there is no **IconFont ** in antd

Comment: You are wrong. In antd page from icon components if you scroll to the bottom you can see "Use iconfont.cn"

Comment: did you install **@ant-design/icons** brfore using these icons

Comment: Yes sure, but trying to set the color fron style or from props doesn't work but for example if as style I place fontSize: 20 the size change

Comment: I tried it in codesandbox it seems the color is changed

Comment: Can you share the link? I wanna try it